# kernel-firmware is a duplicate with kernel-firmware Cent OS YUM

Tags: linux, centos, web-server, yum, update

I am having isssues getting my server to run after yum update was interrupted. When trying to complete the yum update I am getting the following response.

```
[root@RESCUE-web yum.repos.d]# sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.steadfast.net
 * epel: mirrors.servercentral.net
 * extras: mirror.steadfast.net
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-suhosin-0.9.29-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-suhosin-0.9.29-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-intl.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-intl.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.50()(64bit) for package: php-intl-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicuio.so.50()(64bit) for package: php-intl-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.50()(64bit) for package: php-intl-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.50()(64bit) for package: php-intl-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-xmlrpc.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package php-xmlrpc.x86_64 0:5.4.24-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libicu-last.x86_64 0:50.1.2-10.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-suhosin-0.9.29-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-suhosin-0.9.29-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-6.el6_2.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-suhosin-0.9.29-2.el6.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Removing: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Updated By: php-common-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
Error: Package: php-suhosin-0.9.29-2.el6.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Removing: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Updated By: php-common-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.noarch is a duplicate with kernel-firmware-2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.noarch
kernel-headers-2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with kernel-headers-2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `yum-complete-transaction`? If `yum` was interrupted, it should have printed a warning telling you to do this. You should do so before attempting to do *anything* else.

Comment: I have already run yum-complete-transaction. If i try and run it again I get "No unfinished transactions left" I have also now resolved the rpmdb problems for the kernel firmware but not the php-suhosin package errors

Comment: suhosin is not compatible with PHP 5.4. You'll have to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, managed to get YUM to finish all updates. However I still cannot access the server. If I ping the IP address it just timeouts. The server is a virtual machine at rackspace cloud. I have tried to update iptables to ensure the firewall isn't blocking connections but when trying to save with **sudo service iptables save** I get the following error: **Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory**. Where to go from here?

Comment: Just to be clear the only way I am able to access the server is my mounting the drive and chroot into the mount.

Comment: Sounds like you have problems completely unrelated to this question. Perhaps you should put together a new question?