# Cent OS webserver unreachable (SSH or HTTP and Ping timeout) after YUM update

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, ssh, web-server

I have recently tried to update my Cent OS web server with YUM update which was interrupted. This caused some issues and took there server offline. See the following question for details of this:
[kernel-firmware is a duplicate with kernel-firmware Cent OS YUM](https://serverfault.com/questions/571474/kernel-firmware-is-a-duplicate-with-kernel-firmware-cent-os-yum)

I have fully resolved these issues now but I am still unable to access the server and the only way of doing so is using rescue mode to mount the drive and chroot into the mount. When I ping the server IP address it just timeouts.

The server is a virtual machine at rackspace cloud. I have tried to update iptables to ensure the firewall isn't blocking connections but when trying to save with **sudo service iptables** save I get the following error: **Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory**.

Where do I go from here to get the server back online?

Comment: Are you sure it's a firewall issue? Have you tried to boot the server and watch the [console](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/do-you-provide-console-access) for any problems?

Comment: It quite possibly has nothing to do with the firewall at all. I cannot boot and watch console if it is a remote virtual machine with rackspace can I?

Comment: How are you chrooting ? Are you sure you have mounted the proc FS before chroot? example: `mount -t proc none /mnt/proc` Also have you checked the logs of your chrooted system?

Comment: **[root@RESCUE-web ~]# mount /dev/xvdb1 /mnt** and then
**[root@RESCUE-web ~]# chroot /mnt**

I am trying to look at the logs now but not sure which one to be looking at, boot seems fine.

Comment: Try to mount the proc,sys and dev FS before you chroot: `mount /dev/xvdb1 /mnt` then `mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc` 
`mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys` and `mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev` afterwards chroot and try to find out why is your system not available. Check /var/log/messages, try to start sshd daemon, check out the firewall, etc.

Comment: Did you click the link I gave you?

Comment: @MichaelHampton what link are you referring to?

Comment: Read my very first comment at the top here.

Comment: @b13n1u I followed your instructions and the last update in /var/log/messages was Jan 29 22:01:13. I have tried this: **service sshd start sshd** but the response is **sshd: unrecognised service**

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry I didn't see the link, well I have tried it anyway and it won't work! Probably because I am on a Mac!

Comment: It looks like your system is not booting at all. You should try to  connect through the console. According to the link provided by MichaelHampton, it is an Ajax web terminal so it does not matter if you use MacOS.Windows or Linux. Please check out your rackspace control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having followed the helpful comments above by Michael Hampton and b13n1u I contacted Rackspace support and discovered that the **/boot/grub/menu.lst** was not properly formatted.

```
rd_NO_DM rhgb
```

Had to be replaced with

```
initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64.img
```